# Incrementing integer from ArrayList in method won't work?

Tags: c#

```
string popIt(System.Collections.ArrayList pool,ref int spin)   //"EMPTY"/str;++/"OVER"
    {
        if (pool.Count == 0)
        { return "EMPTY"; }
        else
        {
            if (spin < pool.Count) { spin += 1; return pool[spin - 1].ToString(); }
            else { return "OVER"; }
        }
    }
popIt(pools[0], spiners[0]);
```

This won't increment int spiners[0] in ArrayList spinners, it will only increment spin in the method, like VB.NET ByVal. I tried using ref keyword, but I get few errors, how to do this?

Comment: Why are you using ArrayLists? They are a legacy holdover from .net 1.1 and are not really intended for new development. You appear to know how to do what you want to do in VB.NET, can you edit your question to show what you are trying to in vb?

Comment: To change spin value you need to use 'out' keyword.

Comment: @Gleb look at the last line of code he is doing `popIt(pools[0], spiners[0]);` the problem is the object at element 0 of the `spinners` collection is not updating when he updates the value in his function. `out` will not solve that problem.

Comment: I don't know what is unclear @Scott Chamberlain, but I will explain. I have few pools, that are dynamically added to pools, and same number of spinners, also dynamically added, to spinners, so I can get a single argument like: pools[i][spiners[i]] and feed it to a function

Answer (score 0):

So you can do like this:

```
int spin=spiners[0];

popIt(pools[0], ref spin);

spiners[0]=spin;
```

Thats will work, if I correctly understand what you need.

Comment: It gives me an error the best overload method match for 'blabla' has some invalid arguments. like VB byVal, it will create variable int spin and assign it the value of spiners[0]. I want it to be like VB byRef, to create spin, that is pointing to spiners[0], instead of pointing to copy of spiners[0]